# Return table with columns

Tags: postgresql

Here is a simple query that gives expected out.

```
select 1.1 as x, 1.1 as y;
x  |  y
-----+-----
1.1 | 1.1
(1 row)
```

Here the same query is placed inside a function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo4(param integer) 
RETURNS TABLE(x float, y float) AS
$$
DECLARE var float;
BEGIN
  var = 1.1;
  RETURN QUERY select var as x, var as y;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Here is the output:

```
select foo4(4);
foo4
-----------
(1.1,1.1)
(1 row)
```

Why does the function output the data differently? How can I make the function output into two columns?

Using PostgreSQL 10.3 and Windows 7/10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`select * from foo4(4);` should give you the result you are looking for.

Comment: You are correct. Why does the query produce differently output when inside a function?

Comment: @Lars functions always return single values (in most languages). This makes returned data easier to handle. In this particular case, the data returned by `foo4(int)` is of type RECORD. This type can hold a set of values, much like a ROW type can hold an entire row of a table. By doing `select * from myRow or myRecord;`, you are spreading the row or record into columns. Try doing `select * from "table_name"` and `select "table_name" from "table_name";` you'll see what I'm talking about.

Comment: More info here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/plpgsql-declarations.html#PLPGSQL-DECLARATION-RECORDS

Answer (score 0):

Try `RETURN QUERY EXECUTE`.  That will cause the query to be dynamic instead of static.  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#AEN63012

Comment: This has nothing to do with dynamic vs. static SQL.